# React Native Redux don't change state I don't understand why

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I'm using redux and redux-thunk long time, Im trying now this simple workflow but not working the my expected value

actioncreator =>

```
export const openguidelist = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: OPEN_GUIDE_LIST });
  };
};
```

My reducer =>

```
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
      guideopen: true
    };
    export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case OPEN_GUIDE_LIST:
          return { ...state, guideopen: true ? false : true };
        default:
          return state;
      }
};
```

and triggered actioncreator the my component onPress is nothing wrong, by the way Im looking react-native-debugger, initial work is working change the guideopen true to false my expected then guideopen is never change always return false,what I'm expecting is the change in value each time the onpressing triggers but redux don't just change the state first time and than nothing change the guideopen return always the same value (false)  I don't understand why please explain me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`true ? false : true` will always evaluate to `false`.

It should be `guideopen: !state.guideopen`.

Also, if `guideopen` is the only state in the reducer, you can remove the nesting and use the boolean directly as the state:

```
(state = false, action) {
...
case OPEN_GUIDE_LIST: 
  return !state;
```

Comment: Thank you is work and thanks for advice, I'm grateful for that